# How to fix downloading .zip files issue from IIS?

Tags: iis, networking, server, zip, mime-types

I am trying to download a zip file from IIS using the server's public IP, but a "Network Failed" error is always there.
I checked all the solutions here or in other websites about mime types and networking but with no success. Knowing that only .zip files have this problem.
Please help

Comment: Could you please tell me the details codes about downloading zip ? Besides,I guess you may use Chrome to download the files, I suggest you could try to use another browser to download the file.

Comment: Whether I'm using Chrome or Edge for example the issue is the same.
I have some files in the IIS wwwroot folder, and this webservice I'm using for my mobile app, the mobile generates the data as a zip file and then downloads the file. Now this scenario is failing as I explained. 
Even If a try to download the file manually from the server using the server's IP it also fails. 
**Note**: zip files generated by the server (zipped by the server) only have this problem, while other extensions don't, or zip files that were zipped in other machine and moved to the server are downloaded normally.

Comment: Do you mean you genreate the zip file by using your web application codes? Could you please post the codes about how you generate the codes?

Comment: I don't have the source code of the application I'm just preparing the app environment and preparing all the server features and prerequists.
But even if I manually zipped a file on the server, the file could not be downloaded using public IP (local ip works).